# Падает приложение из-за анимации. XAML

Tags: xaml, анимация

Происходит вылет приложения Windows Phone 8.1 при срабатывании анимации. Сокращенный вариант разметки выглядит следующим образом:

```
<Page
x:Class="Eskb.Pages.Indications"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Eskb.Pages"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="#f4f4f4"
RequestedTheme="Light">
<Page.Resources>
    <!-- Вот эта анимация -->
    <Storyboard x:Name="Expand_Indications">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Triangle_DropDown"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Points">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,7 4,0 8,7"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
<!-- Если в этом месте подпишемся на событие Тапа, то во время тапа по Гриду приложение упадет-->
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
        <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Expand_Indications}"/>
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
<Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding MyElements}">
    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Listbox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Height="400">
                            <!-- Если в этом месте подписаться на событие Тапа, то во время тапа по Бордеру ничего не произорйдет -->
                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                    <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Expand_Indications}"/>
                                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                            <!-- Тот самый анимируемый элемент -->
                            <Polygon x:Name="Triangle_DropDown"
                                     Points="0,0 4,7 8,0"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </listBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Есть идеи, господа?